# vscode debug suite all of a sudden can not find Django module

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I've had my vscode integrated with my Django project perfectly fine for about a month now. I went home for the weekend and all of a sudden this morning my vscode debug suite is not working. I could almost swear that I have not touched anything since last time it was working, but I suppose it's possible I may have done something.

**NOTE**: The following command fails when I have vscode run it, but when I open `python manage.py shell`, I can do `from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line` perfectly fine.

I'm trying to run the test suite on all my tests, but after running the following command (I put on separate lines for readability) I get an error. I have ran this test inside and outside of my virtual environment and nothing neither works.

```
/Users/hgducharme/Programming/webapp ; 
env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=webapp.settings.development 
PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8 
PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 
/usr/local/bin/python3-32 
/Users/hgducharme/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2019.8.30787/pythonFiles/ptvsd_launcher.py 
--default --client --host localhost --port 52944 
/Users/hgducharme/Programming/webapp/manage.py test apps/tests/
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/hgducharme/Programming/webapp/manage.py", line 10, in main
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named 'django'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/hgducharme/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2019.8.30787/pythonFiles/ptvsd_launcher.py", line 43, in <module>
    main(ptvsdArgs)
  File "/Users/hgducharme/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2019.8.30787/pythonFiles/lib/python/ptvsd/__main__.py", line 432, in main
    run()
  File "/Users/hgducharme/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2019.8.30787/pythonFiles/lib/python/ptvsd/__main__.py", line 316, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target, run_name='__main__')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/runpy.py", line 240, in run_path
    pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/Users/hgducharme/Programming/webapp/manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/hgducharme/Programming/webapp/manage.py", line 16, in main
    ) from exc
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

**.vscode/launch.json**

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [{
            "name": "All tests",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "stopOnEntry": true,
            "pythonPath": "${config:python.pythonPath}",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/manage.py",
            "args": [
                "test",
                "apps/tests/",
            ],
            "env": {},
            "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.vscode/.env",
            "justMyCode": false,
        },
    ]
}
```

**settings.json**

```
{
    "python.testing.unittestArgs": [
        "-v",
        "-s",
        "./apps/tests",
        "-p",
        "test_*.py"
    ],
    "python.testing.pytestEnabled": false,
    "python.testing.nosetestsEnabled": false,
    "python.testing.unittestEnabled": true,
    "python.pythonPath": "/usr/local/bin/python3-32",
    "python.formatting.provider": "black",
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
    "python.linting.flake8Enabled": false,
}
```

**pip freeze**

```
appdirs==1.4.3
astroid==2.2.5
atomicwrites==1.3.0
attrs==19.1.0
black==19.3b0
certifi==2019.6.16
chardet==3.0.4
Click==7.0
Django==2.2.2
django-crispy-forms==1.7.2
django-debug-toolbar==2.0
django-redis==4.10.0
idna==2.8
importlib-metadata==0.19
isort==4.3.21
lazy-object-proxy==1.4.1
mccabe==0.6.1
more-itertools==7.2.0
packaging==19.1
pluggy==0.12.0
py==1.8.0
pylint==2.3.1
pyparsing==2.4.2
pytest==5.0.1
pytz==2019.1
redis==3.2.1
requests==2.22.0
six==1.12.0
sqlparse==0.3.0
toml==0.10.0
typed-ast==1.4.0
urllib3==1.25.3
wcwidth==0.1.7
wrapt==1.11.2
xmltodict==0.12.0
zcrmsdk==1.0.8
zipp==0.5.2
```

Comment: Wow. I had my python version set to 3.4... I'm actually an idiot. What do I do with this question now? Leave it so I can help out the other dummies?

Comment: you can put an answer on how you have resolved it

Comment: First, upgrade your python to 3.7, then create the virtual environment again.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you don't have any dependency installations so install virtual env, activate and then install the requirements
2. Make sure you activate and run the server, so that application works fine.
3. If the server works fine, we can run the tests.